# Is a call to a RPG program from C# synchronous or not?

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange, rpg

My C# code calls a program in AS400 with cwbx API.
Now the question is : is that call synchronous? I mean, upon returning to my code, how can I be sure the called program has its job done?

It seems that the called program does its job but sometimes not fast enough, so that's why I suspect that maybe the call is asynchronous. But I don't know how cwbx.dll works.
I checked the help document http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v5r4/en_US/rpc1.pdf but nothing is said about synchronous or asynchronous calls.

```
cwbx.Program program = new cwbx.Program();
program.LibraryName = Main.GetBIBAS400();
/* ... */
program.Call(parameters);
```

If the call is synchronous, all is good for me. And it might be so as the API structure is quite simple.
But if it's asynchronous, what can I code to wait for the result of my RPG program?

Comment: Which page of the pdf contains the method?

Comment: Shouldn't matter if client side is wrapped in async code. It's Preferable anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the call is synchronous.

The document you linked to has nothing to do with the Active X components on a client PC.

As part of the older **IBM i Access for Windows** install or the newer **Access Client Solution - Windows Application Package** you should have the **Programmer's Toolkit** option installed.

The ActiveX components are documented there
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WaitHandle class to ensure that your code blocks until it the .dll is done processing.

Specifically, check out the [WaitOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.8) method for achieving this.  Example below:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main starting.");

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            new WaitCallback(WorkMethod), autoEvent);

        // Wait for work method to signal.
        if(autoEvent.WaitOne(1000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Work method signaled.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timed out waiting for work " +
                "method to signal.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Main ending.");
    }

    static void WorkMethod(object stateInfo) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Work starting.");

        // Call your external dll here
        program.Call(parameters);

        // Signal that work is finished.
        Console.WriteLine("Work ending.");
        ((AutoResetEvent)stateInfo).Set();
    }
```